# create a new array with the difference between values of the first array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array of values.

```
$array = [1,3,6,7,9,12];
```

the new array to obtain is the difference between values.

in new array:

```
$new_array[0] = 0;
$new_array[1] = $array[1] - $array[0];
....
.....
$new_array[n] = $array[n] - $array[n-1];
```

based on the $array example, the new array to obtain is:

```
$new_array = [0,2,3,1,2,3];
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: So what exactly is your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = [1,3,6,7,9,12];
$new_array = array();

# Proceed if array has more than 1 element
if(sizeof($array) > 1) {
    for ($a = 0; $a < sizeof($array); $a++) {
        # Just a check
        if (isset($array[$a - 1]))
            # (Current position) - (current position - 1) 
            # Because array started at position 1 and not 0
            $new_array[] = $array[$a] - $array[$a - 1];
        else
            # Nothing to compare then set it to 0
            $new_array[] = $array[$a] - $array[$a];
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [1,3,6,7,9,12];
$new_array = array(0);

if (count($array) > 1) { //Check if array has more than 2 elements
    for($i = 1; $i <= count($array) - 1; $i++) {
        $new_array[$i] = $array[$i] - $array[$i - 1]; //Make the calculation here
    }
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

Result:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => int 0
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 1
  4 => int 2
  5 => int 3
```